# docker-compose build and docker build do not share layer cashing when copying files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I build a multi-stage docker build with `docker-compose build` the docker layer cashing does not transfer to `docker build .` command

In the logs provided below you'll see that the `WORKDIR` command uses the docker layer cashing but `COPY` ignores it and creates a new hash. (the files have not been changed at all).

This does not occur when I use **only** `docker build` or `docker-compose` build.
Here are the logs of the builds:

```
T02429:app$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node                10                  9b9d314e0a86        7 hours ago         904MB
T02429:app$ docker-compose build test
Building test
Step 1/6 : FROM node:10 as base
 ---> 9b9d314e0a86
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in fc2d962f4fd0
Removing intermediate container fc2d962f4fd0
 ---> 362c0b907170
Step 3/6 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> 7457757e0221
Step 4/6 : COPY yarn.lock ./
 ---> 8bb824d2d7cd
Step 5/6 : COPY jest.config.js ./
 ---> 584c78a1cce8
Step 6/6 : COPY src src
 ---> 8d7aac67a142

Successfully built 8d7aac67a142
Successfully tagged test_image:latest
T02429:app$ docker build -t full_build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon    255kB
Step 1/12 : FROM node:10 as base
 ---> 9b9d314e0a86
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 362c0b907170
Step 3/12 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> 48e89caded31
Step 4/12 : COPY yarn.lock ./
 ---> 58c942524315
Step 5/12 : COPY jest.config.js ./
 ---> 02b7f45d1d90
Step 6/12 : COPY src src
 ---> 708fe2761b39
Step 7/12 : FROM node:10 as prod
 ---> 9b9d314e0a86
Step 8/12 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 362c0b907170
Step 9/12 : COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/package.json package.json
 ---> 542eacbc1285
Step 10/12 : COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/src src
 ---> c40cbe92f9ec
Step 11/12 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 66473d8427c7
Removing intermediate container 66473d8427c7
 ---> f5b1b1deafab
Step 12/12 : CMD [ "echo", "hello world" ]
 ---> Running in a8c4609e7159
Removing intermediate container a8c4609e7159
 ---> 863470696544
Successfully built 863470696544
Successfully tagged full_build:latest
```

This is my docker file:

```
# The instructions for the first stage
FROM node:10 as base
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY jest.config.js ./
COPY src src

# The instructions for second stage
FROM node:10 as prod
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/package.json package.json
COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/src src

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "echo", "hello world" ]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    image: web_image:latest
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod
  test:
    image: test_image:latest
    build:
      context: .
      target: base
    environment:
      - CI=true
    command: echo Hello
```